# ¹H-MRS Detection of Dopamine

Tags: organic-chemistry, biochemistry, spectroscopy

Why is it difficult to detect [dopamine](http://www.hmdb.ca/spectra/nmr_one_d/1070) using $\ce{^1H}$ Magnetic Resonance Spectroscopy (MRS) in the brain (*in vivo*)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. The concentration of dopamine is low
2. The concentration of other protons is very high
3. The magnetic field is not homogeneous.
4. The brain cannot be rapidly rotated the way a laboratory solution state NMR sample is to average magnetic field inhomogenity
5. Compare to laboratory solution state NMR, the viscosity in the brain would be high causing further line broadening.

If you look at the spectra in [1H NMR Probe for in Situ Monitoring of Dopamine Metabolism and Its Application to Inhibitor Screening](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ja305051u) J. Am. Chem. Soc., 2012, 134 (30), pp 12398–12401, you'll see that even in tissue samples, there are too many other stronger signals for conventional 1H NMR to be successful, so C-13 labeling is used in combination with 1H NMR.

Comment: Thanks for this answer and the reference. Concerning 2, is there a way to suppress other signal sources, as is done with water, or are there too many sources on the same "wavelength"? Concerning 3, is "shimming" not enough because of the low concentration? Concerning 4, the gradient coils are rotated around the head - does the problem concern the main field B0? Concerning 5, could some kind of contrast be used, similar to BOLD, to address this, noninvasively?

Comment: For 2, there are signals that are very overlapping, if you can see in the paper. For 3, having spent countless hours shimming, it is never fully successful on a 5mm sample; but to the degree a field is uniform in a 5mm sample (say to 1 ppb inhomogenity), it would be much worse in a meter scale sample (maybe even 1ppm) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shim_(magnetism).  4. There should be no gradient in the field for the an NMR peak to approach its natural line width.  5. Contrast agents change relaxation rates, which is the basis for MRI, but (continues below)

Comment: (continued from about) if you want to detect a particular compound, you need to look at chemical shift not relaxation rate.

Comment: Hypothetically speaking, if the dopamine peak would not be overlapping with anything else, would it help to use multiple averages to overcome the problem of low concentration?

Comment: @noumenal In the article "Dopamine Reduction in the Substantia Nigra of Parkinson's Disease Patients Confirmed by In Vivo Magnetic Resonance Spectroscopic Imaging", it is stated that be adding spectra of whole groups of patients together, information of dopamine concentrations can be obtained, but not for an individual. http://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0084081